# How one can travel to Astral Realms like Indraloka or Vaikuntha etc. without being dead? Is there any method described in Shastras??

Tags: lokas

The saint Tukaram is very famous in Maharashtra who had travelled to Vaikuntha with his human body. It is said that Lord Vishnu himself came to take him to His abode. Who else have travelled to Astral realms with the human body? I have read about many Yogis who can travel to astral realms but not with the material body but with an astral one. How is this possible? Do Shastras or Tantra books or Puranas have described methods of astral travelling?

Comment: "Who else have travelled to Astral realms with the human body?"- Arjuna & Krishna, Revata & Revati, Yudhisthira, Nuhusha, Yayati, Ravana etc...